# name 'requests' is not defined

Tags: python, docker, flask

getting name 'requests' is not defined error on my pod's container when i run "curl -X POST http://192.168.99.101:30117/api -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{"message" : "Game"}' command.

Docker file :-

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-python3
MAINTAINER "Gaurav Agnihotri"
#choosing /usr/src/app as working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Mentioned python module name to run application
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
# Exposing applicaiton on 80 so that it can be accessible on 80
EXPOSE 80
#Copying code to working directory
COPY . .
#Making default entry as python will launch api.py
CMD [ "python3", "m1.py" ]
~
```

requirements.txt :-

```
Flask==1.1.1
requests
```

m1.py:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import request
import urllib
import json
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def api():
    user_data = request.get_json()
    data = user_data['message']
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/reverse', json={'message': data })
    json_resp = r.json()
    a = random.uniform(0, 10)
    return jsonify({"rand": a, "message": json_resp.get("message")})
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

ERROR:-

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/src/app/m1.py", line 13, in api
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/reverse', json={'message': data })
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

Comment: What if you add `print(requests)` directly after the line `import requests`?

Comment: To help diagnose, I would suggest using an official Python image, such as "3.7-alpine" (https://hub.docker.com/_/python)